# SignalR Azure Functions resulted only one output binding is supported

Tags: azure-functions, signalr

I have an Azure Functions with SignalR built using .NET 7 (dotnet-isolated). A few days ago it had no problem. But now it generete an error message.

> System.InvalidOperationException: Only one output binding is supported
> when using a binding assigned to '$return'. Found a total of 2
> bindings. For more information:
> https://aka.ms/dotnet-worker-poco-binding.

```
[Function("broadcast")]
[SignalROutput(HubName = "brick_broadcaster", ConnectionStringSetting = "signalrConnection")]
public SignalRMessageAction Broadcast([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")] HttpRequestData req, FunctionContext functionContext)
{
    using var bodyReader = new StreamReader(req.Body);
    return new SignalRMessageAction("brick")
    {
        Arguments = new[] { bodyReader.ReadToEnd() },
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved this problem. The problem appeared when I updated the [Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker) to version [1.16.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk/1.16.2). Now I downgrade to lower version [1.15.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk/1.15.1) and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been fixed in 1.16.3.  https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/pull/2098/commits/674fccba90497f1b8e5784b688b930c2cc4318a6

OP's ticket in Github: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/2073